# Smart Contract Withdrawal from contract owner

Tags: solidity

For example I don't want to store ETH on Smart Contract but to the contract owner. Then how to implement withdrawal from the contract owner?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

    contract WDfromContractOwner {
    
       address public owner;
    
        constructor() {
         owner=msg.sender;
        }
    
        function deposit() external payable returns (bool) {     
        payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
        return true;
        }
    
        function withdrawal() external returns (bool) {     
         
          // Witdrawal from owner address....???

        return true;
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart contract is not able to pull **ETH** from an address (other than the address sending the ETH to the contract). The transfer needs to always be originated from and signed by the sender (in your case the `owner`).

---

However, it can pull **tokens** owned by an address. The sender (`owner`) needs to `approve()` the amount at first, interacting with the token contract from their address. Then your contract can invoke the token's `transferFrom()` function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address, address, uint256) external returns (bool);
}

contract WDfromContractOwner {
    address public owner;

    function withdrawToken() external {
        // Only reachable from the mainnet.
        // Transfers from other networks (such as Remix VM) will fail.
        address mainnetUSDT = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7;
        address receiver = msg.sender; // address of the user executing the `withdrawToken()`
        uint256 amount = 5 * 1e6; // 5 USDT, 6 decimals
        require(
            // the `owner` needs to execute `approve()` on the token contract directly from the `owner` address
            // so that the `WDfromContractOwner` contract can spend their tokens
            IERC20(mainnetUSDT).transferFrom(owner, receiver, amount)
        );
    }
}
```

You can get the approved amount using web3.js:

```
const USDTAddress = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7";
const ownerAddress = "0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF";

// just the `balanceOf()` is sufficient in this case
const ABI = [
    {"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}
];

const USDTContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, USDTAddress);
const approved = await USDTContract.methods.balanceOf(ownerAddress).call();
console.log(approved);
```

Comment: Very perfect. But just for additional, can we show to the users or via web3 front end how much amount that the owner has currently approved? So user can see WD process is enable or disabled at the time he wants to WD.

Comment: @cempaka Sure, I updated my answer with a JS snippet to check the approved value. Note that the `approved` value is an unsigned integer including decimal places (USDT has 6 decimal places), so `1` USDT is actually going to be returned as `1000000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already are transferring the funds to the owner each time an user deposit it should not be necessary, but if you want you could do it anyway, you have different options like passing the amount as a parameter, have a default or a minimum amount, etc, but for simplicity to withdraw all the funds just add this two lines in the function

```
(bool result,)= payable(owner).call{value: address(this).balance }("");
return result
```